# Get number line of file text in c

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, numbers, line

How do get number line of file text on c ?. Help me .
Get sum number line. 
I want read a file text. 
EX:

```
for( line = 0; line < sumline; line ++) {
 printf("char in line");
}
```

Comment: do u want to count how many lines are in your file?

Comment: It is unclear what you are looking for. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case i understood the question :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
   FILE *fp;
   char * line;
   size_t  len = 0;
   ssize_t read;

   int lines = 0;

   fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
   if( fp != NULL ){
      while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1){
         lines ++;
         printf("%s\n", line);
      }
      fclose(fp);
   }


   printf("number of lines : %d\n", lines);
}
```

to count how many lines in your file

Comment: if  i search number line. How i can read content in line
`int i;
for(i = 0; i < line; i++) {
 $content = // content of file ?
}`

Comment: the content of each line of the file is read into `line`

Comment: Code c on linux.
File text:
`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
10 82 21 32 12 32`
How i can get content of file.
I want read file and get array
ex:
`while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1){
 array a[100] = (number in line ex: {1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9})
}`

Comment: man!!! who can understand your comment ? please `edit` your question with very easy and clear English. We are just guessing and answering! do some effort

Comment: end of page. i had answers

Comment: @user3569811 really?!! I see that you have 6 answers here on your question but none is marked as `accepted` ? `SO` is a place where all Q-A are intended to be preserved for the future use. if you had an answer pls consider adding it here at least as a reward to the guys who spent effort to answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   `int lines = 0;
   while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
       lines++;
   }
   cout << lines << endl;`
```

Comment: `cout` is not C. And please avoid code-only answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to get the number of lines inside a file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// get the number of lines inside file
int getLineCnt(char *pcFileName) {
  FILE *fp;
  int lines=0;

  fp = fopen(pcFileName, "r");
  if(fp == NULL) { return -1; }

  while (EOF != (fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n]"), fscanf(fp, "%*c"))) {
    ++lines;
  }

  io_fclose(fp);    

  return lines; ///\ retval number of lines
}
```